# Full calendar " Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I'm trying to add a calendar to my web app but it's not working. I followed the instructions below and I can't get the calendar to populate.

Do I need to write all the Javascript as well? This seems like a quick step to install a calendar. I'm sure I'm missing some steps for installation but this is what I found online.

Add to gemfile

```
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
```

2. Bundle install and restart rails server.

3. Add to application.js

```
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
```

4. Add to host.html.erb and use script code

   ```
     <script>

       window.reservations = <%= raw @events.to_json %>
       window.days = <%= raw @days.to_json %>

       function showReservations(data) {
         return data.map(function (e) {
           if (e['start_date'] !== e['end_date']) {
             e['end_date'] = moment.utc(e['end_date']).add(1, 'days')
           }

           return {
             name: e.fullname,
             start: e['start_date'],
             end: e['end_date'],
             avatar: e.image,
             status: e.status
           }
       });
     };

     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
         left: 'title',
         center: '',
         right: 'prev,next'
       },
       defaultDate: $('#start-date').val(),
       events: showReservations(reservations),
       eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
         return $(`
           <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end">
             <div class="fc-content ${event.status}">
               <span class="fc-title"><img class="img-circle avatar-small" src="${event.avatar}"> ${event.name}</span>
             </div>
           </a>
         `);
       },
       dayRender: function(date, cell) {
         var dayInfo = $.grep(days, function(e) {
           return e.day === date.format();
         });

         console.log(dayInfo);

         <% if !@rooms.blank? %>
           if (dayInfo.length > 0) {
             if (dayInfo[0].status == "Not_Available") {
               cell.addClass('fc-past');
             } else {
               cell.append('<span class="day-price">' + '$' + dayInfo[0].price + '</span>')
             }
           } else {
             cell.append('<span class="day-price">' + '$<%= @room.price %>' + '</span>')
           }
         <% end %>


       },
       selectable: true,
       select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
         var start_date = moment(start);
         var end_date = moment(end).subtract(1, "days");

         <% if @rooms.blank? %>
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
         <% end %>

         var overlap = reservations.filter(function(e) {
           var r_start_date = moment(e.start_date);
           var r_end_date = moment(e.end_date).subtract(1, "days");

           return (r_start_date.isSameOrBefore(end_date) && r_end_date.isSameOrAfter(start_date))
         }).length > 0;

         if(start.isBefore(moment()) || overlap) {
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect')
         } else {
           $('#new_calendar').modal('show');

           $('#calendar_start_date').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
             setDate: start_date
           });
           $('#calendar_start_date').val(start_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

           $('#calendar_end_date').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
             setDate: end_date
           });
           $('#calendar_end_date').val(end_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
         }
     },
   }
     $('.fc-prev-button').click(function() {
       var current = new Date($('#start-date').val());
       var prev = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() - 1, 1)
       $('#start-date').val(moment(prev).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
       $('#start-date').trigger('change')
     });

     $('.fc-next-button').click(function() {
       var current = new Date($('#start-date').val());
       var next = new Date(current.getFullYear(), current.getMonth() + 1, 1)
       $('#start-date').val(moment(next).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
       $('#start-date').trigger('change')
     });


    </script>
   ```

The error in the console is 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Comment: is this the gem: https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails if so, install seems similar but not exactly the same - try it with the above and see. (just use the simplest example from above link to see if it works, rather than the long bit of js you've got above). Secondly: have you tried `spring restart` ? it's voodoo, but sometimes it Just Works.

Comment: But I don't use spring in this project, I am newbie and I don't remember use it in this project. Is this gen load by default?

Comment: Just try it... if it works, then that was your problem ;) (this is why it's voodoo) :D

Comment: You are really scaring me :(

I put it but the terminal show this error:
`dmuino@Diegos-MBP:~/Desktop/API$ spring restart
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      minitest (~> 5.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Version: 2.0.2

Usage: spring COMMAND [ARGS]

Commands for spring itself:

  binstub         Generate spring based binstubs. Use --all to generate a binstub for all known commands. Use --remove to revert.
  help            Print available commands.
  server...`

Comment: Those look like warnings rather than errors...